# Executing offlineimap through a python script on Windows (through cygwin terminal)

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, cygwin

I am currently working on a python script to automatically parse a large amount of emails created by a registration form. Due to constraints outside my control, the way I chose to do this is to mirror all mails through offlineimap, run a script that processes all mails and files the relevant info into the right places and then run offlineimap again to move all processed mail into a different folders. Being on Windows(7), I run offlineimap through the Cygwin Terminal.

In order to allow not-so-tech-versed colleagues use my script, I wanted to include both runs of offlineimap into the script using:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("offlineimap", shell=True, timeout=20)
```

I get as a result:

```
CompletedProcess(args='offlineimap', returncode=1)
```

Sadly I'm rather new to Python and the subprocess.run command appears to be so new that google didn't yield too many examples. But the problem appears to be that offlineimap is run in the Windows command shell and it fails.

So the solutions to my problem would be either:

a) utilize the cygwin terminal through python

b) run offlineimap through the windows command shell

Sadly the documentation of offlineimap only mentions Windows in passing and the tool seems to be written to be run on linux machines. So I'm not holding my breath for option b) but any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: `run` returns the output. You could try to print it.

Comment: The "CompleteProcess...." statement is the output run gives.
    returncode=0 would indicate a successful execution. Sadly neither google nor the python documentation talk about positive values and what they mean.

Comment: I thought you stated `returncode=1` in your question. of course running cygwin commands in the windows shell doesn't work. but I think you can run a cygwin bash with the process instead. That would work

Comment: Thank you! @Jean-FrançoisFabre

You put me on the path to research command console execution of scripts in cygwin.
`subprocess.run("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe -l -c offlineimap", shell=True)` does the trick and returns `CompletedProcess(args='C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe -l -c offlineimap`, returncode=0)' indicating a successful execution